# How to find ith substring of a string using suffix array and LCP array?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, time-complexity, suffix-array

If we arrange all the **distinct** sub-strings of a string lexicographically and we need the i'th substring

1.) Is it possible to find it using it's [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) and [LCP array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array)?

2.) If Yes, how do we do it ? can it be done in O(Nlog^N) while creating the suffix array using Manber & Myers which has a time complexity of O(Nlog^2N) or while creating it's LCP array using kasai's algorithm which has a time complexity of O(N)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done using Suffix array and LCP array.

Assuming you know how to calculate Suffix array and LCP array.

Let `p[]` denote suffix array `lcp[]` denote LCP array.

create a array which store the number of distinct sub string till `i'th` rank suffix. This can be calculated using this formula. For more details see [Here](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/suffix_array)

[image]

Let `cum[]` denote cumulative array which can be calculated as follow:

```
cum[0] = n - p[0];
for i = 1 to n do:
    cum[i] = cum[i-1] + (n - p[i] - lcp[i])
```

Now for finding `i'th` sub string just find the lower bound of `i` in cumulative array `cum[]` that will give you rank of suffix from where your sub string should start and print all character till length of

```
i - cum[pos-1] + lcp[pos] // i lies between cum[pos-1] and cum[pos] so for finding 
                          // length of sub string starting from cum[pos-1] we should 
                          // subtract cum[pos-1] from i and add lcp[pos] as it is 
                          // common string between current rank suffix and 
                          // previous rank suffix.
```

where `pos` is value return by lower bound.

Whole above process can be summarized as follow:

```
string ithSubstring(int i){
    pos = lower_bound(cum , cum + n , i);
    return S.substr(arr[pos] , i - cum[pos-1] + lcp[pos]);// considering S as original character string 
}
```

For full implementation of Suffix array , LCP and above logic you can see [Here](http://ideone.com/8dy7Yq)

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response, I have been figuring this out for days. I'll understand and implement this asap and accept this as an answer. :)

Comment: I have added link to full implementation of above logic you can check that if you get any problem understanding that.

Comment: Not yet , I have just recently learned the O(N) and O(log^N) algorithms to create the suffix arrays, it takes time to grasp all the implementations since I am new to this topic

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now

Comment: @sudoer How would I print all substrings from lcp?

Comment: @te7 I didn't get you, can you please explain.

Comment: @sudoer I want to traverse all the substrings using the suffix array and the lcp. If you have a suggestion, possibly could you just edit your answer above to include that.